# Will the origin of anecdote in paper violate double-blind policy?

Tags: conference, peer-review, paper-submission, anonymity

A paper I am writing utilizes a short story from Japan to make a point. In the paper, I have written the punch-line in Japanese, with a translation added.

I am not from Japan, but would such an inclusion be considered a violation of double-blind policy ? I am okay with removing the Japanese text, but the story itself needs to stay.

Comment: Why would it be considered a violation? It doesn't make you more identifiable. Given that you're not Japanese it may do the opposite.

Comment: I'm a little confused - the meaning of double-blind only refers to how the study is conducted, and has absolutely no connection to what happens after the study is over. As I'm not sure how the paper you are writing is an experiment, or will be used in an experiment, I can't figure out how double-blind comes into your scenario. Can you clarify what you are doing and why you think what you propose to do would be unacceptable?

Comment: @BrianDHall: I assume this refers to double-blind reviewing (where the author doesn't know who the reviewers are and the reviewers don't know who the author is).

Comment: why is this tagged with 'conference'? Is this a conference with a double-blind review process? I don't understand the concerns at all, please elaborate.

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician Ah, that would fit the peer-review tag, so that would be sensible. Though I don't see how a short-story would violate double-blind reviewing, that still makes a lot more sense than study design!

Comment: The question in the title and the question in the text do not seem to match.  What do you mean to ask?  As for the question in the text, is there a reason you think it would be a violation?  From what you've said there's no evidence this would be a give-away to your identity, though one could imagine situations where it could.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Double-blind reviewing is about trying to make *you* non-identifiable.  The only way I can see this violating a double-blind policy is if you are well known by your scientific community as the only one who would both write on your topic and know Japanese.  That seems like a stretch.